# Saber região da cidade a partir do cep

Tags: php, api, cep

Gostaria de saber se alguém já resolveu um problema parecido: no meu sistema tem um formulário e um campo cep, quando o usuário digitar o cep queria saber a região dele se é norte, oeste, leste e etc.... vi que nos correios não informa nada relacionado a região, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Exemplo: o usuário digitará o cep : 01505-010 e o sistema irá dizer de qual região da cidade é este cep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma tabela com as informações:

> ```
> Rondônia  RO  NORTE
> Acre  AC  NORTE
> Amazonas  AM  NORTE
> Roraima   RR  NORTE
> Pará  PA  NORTE
> Amapá AP  NORTE
> Tocantins TO  NORTE
> Maranhão  MA  NORDESTE
> Piauí PI  NORDESTE
> Ceará CE  NORDESTE
> Rio Grande do Norte   RN  NORDESTE
> Paraíba   PB  NORDESTE
> Pernambuco    PE  NORDESTE
> Alagoas   AL  NORDESTE
> Sergipe   SE  NORDESTE
> Bahia BA  NORDESTE
> Minas Gerais  MG  SUDESTE
> Espírito Santo    ES  SUDESTE
> Rio de Janeiro    RJ  SUDESTE
> São Paulo SP  SUDESTE
> Paraná    PR  SUL
> Santa Catarina    SC  SUL
> Rio Grande do Sul RS  SUL
> Mato Grosso do Sul    MS  CENTRO OESTE
> Mato Grosso   MT  CENTRO OESTE
> Goiás GO  CENTRO OESTE
> Distrito Federal  DF  CENTRO OESTE
> ```

Ai quando souber o estado pesquisa nessa tabela a região.
Isso pode estar dentro de um json e o javascript realiza a busca da região pelo estado, ou dentro do banco de dados.

Abaixo a estrutura do banco de dados de CEP dos correios.
Esses seriam os dados possíveis para se extrair através do CEP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Desculpa se eu não detalhei corretamente, mas é a região da cidade

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Acredito que isso não é possível pela base de CEP dos correios.

Comment: Caso te ajudou, marque como reposta da pergunto. Obrigado